# Should I be able to set env variables via a dlv-dap remote connection?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

- Remote OS: **Linux/Fedora 33**
- Language: **golang 1.16**
- VSCode (Mac): **1.63.2**
- dlv: **1.7.3**

Problem:
I have used the `env` and `environment` keys below but it is not setting the environment variable `KUBECONFIG` while debugging my go program. I've tried several permutations to set the `KUBECONFIG` env variable, but to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### launch.json

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  
  "configurations": [
    
    {
      "name": "Connect, build debug and launch",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "debugAdapter": "dlv-dap", // `legacy` by default
      "mode": "auto",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "remotePath": "${workspaceRoot}",
      //"port": 2345,
      "debugServer": 2345,
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "environment": [ 
          {"name": "GODEBUG", "value": "x509ignoreCN=0"},
          {"name": "KUBECONFIG", "value": "$HOME/.kube/config"}
      ],
      "env": { 
        "KUBECONFIG": "/home/hickersonj/.kube/config" 
      },
      "trace": "verbose",
      "showLog": true,
      "KUBECONFIG": "/home/hickersonj/.kube/config",
      "args": ["${env:KUBECONFIG}:/home/hickersonj/.kube/config"]
      //"args": ["--arg1", "value1", "--arg2", "value2"]
      //"substitutePath": [{"from": "/home/hickersonj/build", "to": "/run/media/hickersonj/fedora_endor/build/"}],
    },
  ]
}
```

### This is the output of dlv-dap debug log output:

```
    "mode": "debug",
    "program": "/home/hickersonj/build/git/src",
    "args": [
        "KUBECONFIG",
        ":/home/hickersonj/.kube/config"
    ],
    "backend": "default",
    "stackTraceDepth": 50,
    "hideSystemGoroutines": true
}
2021-12-20T19:39:28-08:00 debug layer=dap building from "/home/hickersonj/build/git/src": [go build -o /tmp/__debug_bin827481439 -gcflags all=-N -l /home/hickersonj/build/git/src]
2021-12-20T19:39:28-08:00 debug layer=dap launching binary '/tmp/__debug_bin827481439' with config: {
    "mode": "debug",
    "program": "/home/hickersonj/build/git/src",
    "args": [
        "KUBECONFIG",
        ":/home/hickersonj/.kube/config"
    ],
    "cwd": "/home/hickersonj/build/git/src",
    "output": "/tmp/__debug_bin827481439",
    "dlvCwd": "/home/hickersonj/build/git/src",
    "backend": "default",
    "stackTraceDepth": 50,
    "hideSystemGoroutines": true
}
```

Comment: Your question is missing a question or even a problem description.

Comment: Thanks @zerkms, this is my first post here I appreciate the suggestion.  I've updated the post to have a question and problem description.

Comment: Currently, No. 
We are looking into a way for dlv dap to process the 'env' property currently. Until then, launch the 'dlv dap' process with the environment variables you want.

And even when we make 'dlv dap' process 'env', we have no further plan to extend it to  'environment' or 'envFile' for remote case.

`dlv dap` exits after each debug session, so I guess you will need to write a custom script to launch a new `dlv dap` whenever you want to debug the remote process. Then, add the env var setup in that script.

Comment: Ah ok that makes a lot more sense that it wasn't working.  And that idea is a good one I'll just update my tasks.json to point to a script with the environment variables defined.

Hmm apparently I don't know how to add multi-line code in a comment so I'll just provide a link instead:
[tasks.json](https://pastebin.com/wXbURyPz)